# Glass Material in Unreal Engine 4 for Virtual Reality (VR)?

Tags: rendering, virtual-reality, unreal-engine4

The glass material(s) that are provided and used by UE4 work very well in regular games however it is very expensive to use in VR.

Are there any glass material(s) or textures out there that work well for VR? My guess is the less transparent the glass; the cheaper it is to render since there will be less reflection/refraction?

Comment: _My guess is the less transparent the glass; the cheaper it is to render since there will be less reflection/refraction_ It's practically the same. Transparency and overdraw are specially heavy on UE4

Comment: Gotcha, do you have any suggestions on a material for VR glass?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Do you need refraction? Specular highlights? SSR?

Comment: I'm not sure, In this case I would like glass that I could use for about 50 different objects in a level (windows, glassware, etc) so it needs to be somewhat cheap. My understanding is SSR is the reflections of light onto other surfaces and specular highlights is like the "lens flare" on the glass? Those two i probably dont need as much as transparency? It all comes down to "will the player notice" and "does this (kinda) look like glass".

Comment: I think for now I might just use nothing for the windows and keep them open. As for glassware I'll have to try and use those assets sparingly.